# Unable to setup Eclipse for Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

Im having trouble installing Eclipse to develop Android apps. I have installed the android-sdk-windows as well as Eclipse Juno (running on Windows 8).

When I start Eclipse I get the message "This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools revision 21.0.0.rc9 or above. Current version is 15.0.0. Please updaye your SDK tools to the latest version"

I then open my SDK manager, and select to update and install the package. But I get the error messages as per the images below
[image]
[image]

Can anyone please help with this as its driving me crazy. I have looked on here for solutions but a lot of the explanations get very technical or skip "obvious" steps and I get stuck. I have installed and unistalled a number of times, but no luck. I have manually tried to change the filename as per the second error message but it says the file is in use so I cant rename it. I have closed all internet explorer applications when trying this, as well as disabling Norton antivirus, but still no luck.

Comment: Close eclipse before you run sdkmanager. Also close any file expolorer windows, and anything else

Comment: Tried that as well but still get the same errors. And I also have closed any open programs and documents, antivirus etc. that I can see is running but still no luck. I have tried deleting the SDK in a hope to reinstall it as well but I cant even do this because its says a file or folder is open in another program. Is there a way in which I can tell in which program one of the files or folders are open in so I can kill it?

Comment: I dont know. You can check whether the directories c:\android sdk windows\tools and c:\android sdk windows\temp exist and delete the ToolPackage.old01 manually. There may be a problem on some systems with spaces in the directory name, so you can try change your directory name. Close everything on your system, especially eclipse, emulator, command prompt window

Comment: In fact, I think your directory name is causing problems. I misread the '-' in your directory name, I thought it was ' '. You should change the '-' to '_'

Comment: You mean change C:\android-sdk-windows to C:\android_sdk_windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your download from this link [Get SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). It have the IDE Eclipse and the installation of the SDK already configured. Maybe this help you..

Comment: Thanks for that, but Ive tried that already. Have even more trouble setting that up, thats why I am trying to set it all up manually.

Comment: After trying this (several times) it finally worked. However, I had to delete the SDK I had installed previously that was causing the errors. And uninstalling it was no easy process...

Answer (score 0):

Exit Eclipse while having the SDK Manager open. Then press Yes. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that didnt work either. Still get the same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download sdk or other stuff. following steps

Pre-requestries : Install Jdk and setting the JAVA_HOME and install eclipse

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help --> Install New Software
2. Click Add, in the top-right Corner
3. In the Add Repository dialog enter "ADT Plugin" for Name & the following URL for Location
   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
4. Click OK
5. In the available software dialog check the Developer Tools and click, Next.
6. Read the license and accept it.
7. That it. Finish.

Hope you got the way.